# One wifi adaptor two interfaces

Tags: networking, wifi

I want to know if it is possible to use just one WIFI Adapter to setup a new network connection without a screen. I am using debian. In order to achieve this task I need to do a series of automatic steps involving a device 1 which is the one that I want to have it connected to the new network, and a mobile phone or something with a screen to use for the setup:

1. Create a new AP on the device 1 for the setup
2. Access to this new AP from another device (ie. mobile)
3. From the same device (mobile), access to a webserver that will be served from the first device that scans nearby networks
4. Select a network and introduce password
5. Now the AP on the first device turns off and it is on the desired network.

I wanted to know if this is achievable with just one wifi adaptor and if so how can I do it or how to search for it on the internet, I've been trying to find a tutorial about this but I found nothing.

PS. if someone has a photon dev kit, it's the same result that I want to achieve.

Comment: The adapter with `#channels <= 2` is an interesting device, if been looking for those. Could you tell me its name, and its vendor/product id from `lsusb` or `lspci -n` (whatever apropriate)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, provided that your device actually supports it.

So, see the output of `iw phy phy0 info` and look for the section titled `valid interface combinations` to see if your device can be used as an AP and a managed interface at the same time.

Comment: interface combinations are not supported :( I'm out of luck. Thanks for your help

Comment: UPDATE, I've tried with another adaptor and it says:         valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
                   total <= 3, #channels <= 2
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
                   total <= 4, #channels <= 1

Comment: Is it possible then? How?

Answer (score 1):

To create an AP from the same wifi interface (the easy way) you should use [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) command line tool:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install
```

To create an AP from the same wifi interface run :

```
create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Modify the `wlan0`,  `MyAccessPoint` and  `MyPassPhrase` with yours.

Connect your mobile device to the AP , open the browser and type IP router to modify the router settings.

To stop the AP : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd>